# Python equivalent to Java's BitSet

Tags: java, python, bitset

Is there a Python class or module that implements a structure that is similar to the BitSet?

Comment: For non-Java programmers, what's a BitSet?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Even if no equivalent exists, there might be a good, pythonic way of solving your problem.

Comment: Basically a BitSet is a string of bits with bitwise operations that can be applied to them. The set can also be extended by appending bits or bitsets to the end of the current bitset

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library.  Try:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at this [implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576738-bitset/) in Python 3.

The implementation basically makes use of the built-in `int` type, which is arbitrary precision integer type in Python 3 (where `long` is the Python 2 equivalent).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

"""
bitset.py

Written by Geremy Condra

Licensed under GPLv3

Released 3 May 2009

This module provides a simple bitset implementation
for Python.
"""

from collections import Sequence
import math

class Bitset(Sequence):
    """A very simple bitset implementation for Python.

    Note that, like with normal numbers, the leftmost
    index is the MSB, and like normal sequences, that
    is 0.

    Usage:
        >>> b = Bitset(5)
        >>> b
        Bitset(101)
        >>> b[:]
        [True, False, True]
        >>> b[0] = False
        >>> b
        Bitset(001)
        >>> b << 1
        Bitset(010)
        >>> b >> 1
        Bitset(000)
        >>> b & 1
        Bitset(001)
        >>> b | 2
        Bitset(011)
        >>> b ^ 6
        Bitset(111)
        >>> ~b
        Bitset(110)
    """

    value = 0
    length = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_sequence(cls, seq):
        """Iterates over the sequence to produce a new Bitset.

        As in integers, the 0 position represents the LSB.
        """
        n = 0
        for index, value in enumerate(reversed(seq)):
            n += 2**index * bool(int(value))
        b = Bitset(n)
        return b

    def __init__(self, value=0, length=0):
        """Creates a Bitset with the given integer value."""
        self.value = value
        try: self.length = length or math.floor(math.log(value, 2)) + 1
        except Exception: self.length = 0

    def __and__(self, other):
        b = Bitset(self.value & int(other))
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __or__(self, other):
        b = Bitset(self.value | int(other))
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __invert__(self):
        b = Bitset(~self.value)
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __xor__(self, value):
        b = Bitset(self.value ^ int(value))
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __lshift__(self, value):
        b = Bitset(self.value << int(value))
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __rshift__(self, value):
        b = Bitset(self.value >> int(value))
        b.length = max((self.length, b.length))
        return b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.value == other.value
        except Exception:
            return self.value == other

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in self[:]:
            s += "1" if i else "0"
        return s

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Bitset(%s)" % str(self)

    def __getitem__(self, s):
        """Gets the specified position.

        Like normal integers, 0 represents the MSB.
        """
        try:
            start, stop, step = s.indices(len(self))
            results = []
            for position in range(start, stop, step):
                pos = len(self) - position - 1
                results.append(bool(self.value & (1 << pos)))
            return results
        except:
            pos = len(self) - s - 1
            return bool(self.value & (1 << pos))

    def __setitem__(self, s, value):
        """Sets the specified position/s to value.

        Like normal integers, 0 represents the MSB.
        """
        try:
            start, stop, step = s.indices(len(self))
            for position in range(start, stop, step):
                pos = len(self) - position - 1
                if value: self.value |= (1 << pos)
                else: self.value &= ~(1 << pos)
            maximum_position = max((start + 1, stop, len(self)))
            self.length = maximum_position
        except:
            pos = len(self) - s - 1
            if value: self.value |= (1 << pos)
            else: self.value &= ~(1 << pos)
            if len(self) < pos: self.length = pos
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterates over the values in the bitset."""
        for i in self[:]:
            yield i

    def __len__(self):
        """Returns the length of the bitset."""
        return self.length
```

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't recommend that in production code but for competitive programming, interview preparation and fun, one should make themselves familiar with bit fiddling.

```
b = 0          # The empty bitset :)
b |= 1 << i    # Set
b & 1 << i     # Test
b &= ~(1 << i) # Reset
b ^= 1 << i    # Flip i
b = ~b         # Flip all
```

Comment: Why is this not recommended in production code? Looks simple and efficient.

Comment: It might be considered obscure by some, and it's very typo-sensitive!
It would be fine packaged in a class, though.

Answer (score 4):

You might like to take a look at a module I wrote called [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) (full documentation [here](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/)), although for simple cases that need to be as fast as possible I'd still recommend [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray).

Some similar questions:

[What is the best way to do Bit Field manipulation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-bit-field-manipulation-in-python/)

[Does Python have a bitfield type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142812/does-python-have-a-bitfield-type)

[Python Bitstream implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450208/python-bitstream-implementations)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of bits is finite, `enum.IntFlag` can be used as a bit set.

See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#intflag